# FutureBuilder doesnt work when used with SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting a `type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>'`

I am simply trying to use a FutureBuilder in conjunction with SharedPreferences to return a string that I have previously stored using SharedPreferences.

[Flutter : 'Future <dynamic>' is not a subtype of type bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232397/flutter-future-dynamic-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-bool)

This stack overflow answer is doing the exact same thing as what I'm doing yet I have an error?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getRoleFuture(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.data == false) {
          return Text("No data");
        }
        else {
          return Text(snapshot.data);
        }
      }
    );
  }

getRoleFuture() async {
    var sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sp.getString("role");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you used snapshot.data as bool in this line

```
if(snapshot.data == false) {
      return Text("No data");
    }
```

where as you set the Future return type as string
maybe if you do this:

```
if(snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data == '') {
      return Text("No data");
    }
    else {
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snapshot with `hasData`.

```
if(snapshot.hasData == false)
```

Gives the return type.

```
Future<String> getRoleFuture() async {
    var sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sp.getString("role");
  }
```

Comment: Same issue, doesn't make a difference

Comment: This is a problem with Future<dynamic>

Comment: Gives return type  'Future<String>' .

Answer (score 0):

In you FutureBuilder future pass a refrence to your function:

> future: getRoleFuture, (**without the parentheses**)

so your code should be something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getRoleFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Text("No data");
    }
    else {
      return Text(snapshot.data);
    }
  }
 );
}

Future<String> getRoleFuture() async {
var sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
return sp.getString("role");
}
```

> We don't use the parentheses in that code because we don't want the function to be called at the point where that code is encountered. Instead, we want to pass a reference to our function into the future.